# Status of representation theory of harmonic weak Maass forms

Tags: modular-forms, automorphic-forms

It is well-known that the classical Hecke Maass/modular forms can be reinterpreted as vectors in irreducible automorphic representations of GL(2). On the contrary, for weak Maass form/weakly holomorphic modular forms, I have heard that people are hoping for a similar representation-theoretic interpretation, which has remained elusive so far.

> Can anyone point me to a survey/any reference that explains why so far, we do not have a representation theory of weak Maass/weakly holomorphic modular forms, parallel to the classical Maass/modular forms?

I have tried to look it up in google. So far I only see results that interpret the (weak) modular forms as characters of affine Lie (super)algebra, which does not seem to be what I want.